# Best practices for maintaining configuration of embedded linux system for production

Tags: linux, git, shell, embedded

I have a small single board computer which will be running a linux distribution and some programs and has specific user configuration, directory structure, permissions settings etc.

My question is, what is the best way to maintain the system configuration for release? In my time thinking about this problem I've thought of a few ideas but each has its downsides.

Configure the system and burn the image to an iso file for distribution
This one has the advantage that the system will be configured precisely the way I want it, but committing an iso file to a repository is less than desirable since it is quite large and checking out a new revision means reflashing the system.

Install a base OS (which is version locked) and write a shell script to configure the settings from scratch.
This one has the advantage that I could maintain the script in a repository and update and config changes by pulling changes to the script and running it again, however now I have to maintain a shell script to configure a system and its another place where something can go wrong.

I'm wondering what the best practices are in embedded in general so that I can maybe implement a good deployment and maintenance strategy.

Comment: I have very little experience of Linux in embedded systems, but generally I suppose you'll want a single file and keep things as simple as possible. Particularly if you want the processors pre-flashed during production (as in, the PCB assembly company receives pre-flashed processors).

Answer (score 1):

Embeddded systems tend to have a long lifetime.  Do not be surprised if you need to refer to something released today in ten years' time.  Make an ISO of the whole setup, source code, diagrams, everything... and store it away redundantly.  Someone will be glad you did a decade from now.  Just pretend it's going to last forever and that you'll have to answer a question or research a defect in ten years.